# Check to see if the letters in a word in another array and return true if all match

Tags: c++

I am making a hangman game and I have to check to see that all the letters in the word are all in right array and then only return true. I am stuck at this point as I do not know how to return true once all the letters are in

I have tried different false and true scenarios but they don't seem to be working. The for loop below is what I have tried to do.

```
// This function returns true if the secret word has been guessed correctly.
// Otherwise, it will return false.

bool iswordcomplete(char secretword[], char rights[]) {
// Task 3. Finish this function
//
// Use a for loop to look at each position of the secret word
//
// If all letters in the secret word is in the rights array,
// return true; otherwise, return false.
//
         for (i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {
            if secretword[i] != rights
                 return false;

         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice you wrote `return false;` twice.

Comment: I am talking about c++/c#

Comment: I checked with true as well

Comment: its c++ language

Comment: In C# this would do the trick: `return secretword.All(s => rights.Any(r => r.Equals(s)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool operator :

```
bool returned = true; //True by default
for (i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) 
{
    if (secretword[i] != rights) // | If test returns false, returned is set to false
        returned &= false;       // | If test returns true, returned stays false if previously set to false
}
return returned;
```

It should put the value at false when the test is false but will not put it back to true

Comment: Why not return as soon as you know the result of the function? This solution goes through the entire loop even after it's known that it will return `false`. And please post real code. This is pseudo code where as the question already provides everything that's needed for an answer with actual code.

Comment: This still goes through the entire loop. The `if` doesn't change anything except that it adds another branch (that the compiler might hopefully omit). You need to either `break`, `return` or otherwise end the loop before it reaches the end or modify the loop condition to account for when `returned` becomes `false`. But the simplest solution is just to use the original strategy of `return false;` whenever you find a case that doesn't match.

Comment: Edited

Other Idea would be to build a function comparing two strings (if you are coding in c#) 

On one hand you have your `string secretword;` looking like `"secretword"`for example

On the other hand a string edited at each letter `string searchword ` looking like `"__________"` then `"s_________"` then `"se__e_____"` then "se__e_w___"` and so on... 
Then test  `if (secretword == testword)`

Comment: Hmm, I think you are heading in the right direction. I am trying something

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {
  if (secretword[i] != rights[i])
   return false;
 }

 return true;

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the content of the `secretword` array cells with the `rights` array pointer: `secretword[i] != rights`.

This is not what you want. 
You want to compare the cells data: `secretword[i] != rights[i]`

In order to know if a letter of `secretword` is in `rights`, you have to loop over `rights` for all letters of `secretword`:

```
bool iswordcomplete(char secretword[], char rights[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(secretword); i++) {
    bool isInRights = false;
    // we loop over all characters of rights. We stop at first match
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(rights) && !isInRights; j++)
    { 
      isInRights = (secretword[i] == rights[j]);
    }
    if (!isInRights)
    {
      // We haven't found anything in right, let's stop
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If we reach this line, all the characters from secretword are in rights
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The array right should contain the letters in the word in any order. They dont have to be in the same position as the secret word

Comment: Note that the question originally had `return false;` in all cases which was changed in this answer but not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got two bags full of letters, bags *A* and *B*. I want to know if bag *A* contains the same letters as bag *B*.

The steps you are following are:

1. Get a letter from bag *A* named *a*. If none are left go to step 4
2. Check if the letter *a* is equal to bag *B*.
3. If it isn't say both bags don't match.
4. Say both bags don't match.

Do you by chance see the flaws in your logic? Hint: steps *2* and *4* seem a bit off.

A naive way to solve this problem, but that would actually work would be:

1. Get a letter from bag *A* named *a*. If none are left go to step 4.
2. Go through all letters in bag *B* trying to find a match with current *a*.
3. If a match is found, go to step 1. If not, both bags don't match. Exit.
4. Bag *A* and bag *B* will contain the same letters only and only if the number of letters in *A* and *B* are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `<algorithm>` library with `std::all_of` and `std::find`. Possible solution would be:

```
bool iswordcomplete(char secretword[], char rights[]) {
    char* s_end = secretword + std::strlen(secretword);
    char* r_end = rights + std::strlen(rights);
    return std::all_of(secretword, s_end, [&rights,&r_end](char ch) {
        return std::find(rights, r_end, ch) != r_end;
    });
}
```